# How can I delete the Time Machine backup files on a Netgear ReadyNAS?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, nas

I use a Netgear ReadyNAS as a Time Machine server. I recently bought a new Mac, and I want to delete the old backups. How do I delete them? It's not possible from the Time Machine interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Finder, click Go => Connect To Server...
2. In the Server Address field, type "afp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" (IP address) or "afp://your-ngnas-name.local"
3. Connect using the credentials you use to connect to the Time Machine service.
4. Finder will open a window in /Volumes/ReadyNAS. You should see a list Time Machine's .sparsebundle files.

At this point, you can delete a .sparsebundle. It's also possible to Ctrl+Click on a .sparsebundle and select "Show Package Contents" to browse inside.

**UPDATE** Sometimes files inside the sparsebundle package or the package itself will be locked, preventing deletion. To unlock: Get Info > General > Locked > *uncheck*.